# Mobile WiFi hotspot does not allow access to Ubuntu Server VM via Putty

Tags: networking, 14.04, virtualbox, putty

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 Server Virtual Machine, it has a static IP address set and I am able to access the VM via Putty using my normal WiFi.

However, if I connect my host machine(Windows) to my mobile's hotspot and try to connect, it keeps failing and displays:-

```
Network Error: Connection timed out
```

I have tried different cell phones and different network providers, it still gives the same error.

Please comment any additional information regarding the VM that is needed.

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: Hello. If you are really running 14.04 it reached EOL a long time ago and is off topic on this site.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 20.04